# var=$((var+1)) in loop doesn't work (only!) when written as a one-liner

Tags: bash

I have tried several ways to increment in a for loop using a bash command. Each time the $VAR goes through the loop it resets. I have add the ouput of both using let and not using let. I am unsure why not using let doesn work but it doesnt ?

My code works correctly when it's written out like this:

```
echo "Initial value: $VAR"
for file in a b c; do
  VAR=$((VAR+1))
  echo "Incremented"
done
echo "Final value: $VAR"
```

but it doesn't work like this:

```
echo "Initial value: $VAR"
for file in a b c; do VAR=$((VAR+1)) echo "Incremented"; done
echo "Final value: $VAR"
```

Similarly, it works when I use `let`:

```
for file in a b c; do let VAR++; echo "Incremented"; done
```

What's the difference?

Comment: This is a command i used in bash. I had the value printed out each iteration and it always printed 1 on the files with the word 'hit' in it.

Comment: I don't think so. I have a Mac from 2011 I think the standard is bash. Ill show you the output on both one moment

Comment: Please do -- a Mac should be using bash 3.2, which is rather old but will certainly support standard POSIX math syntax.

Comment: (BTW, as an aside, `printf "$file "` is a slight bit buggy with unusual names; consider `printf '%s ' "$file"` instead; otherwise, a file with the two characters `\n` its name will have a newline printed, a file with `\t` a tab, `%%` will be printed as `%` instead, etc).

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I am copying your comment into my notes for school . Any conclusion on why the HITS=$((HITS+1)) does not work?

Comment: Oh, actually, seeing your code in context it's obvious. You're missing semicolons. I'll add an answer.

Comment: What a silly mistake . . . Thank you. I put the semicolons in and it worked.

Comment: BTW, as another aside -- all-caps variable names actually aren't good form. See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html, paragraph 4, for POSIX conventions around naming of environment variables, which share a namespace with shell variables (meaning, for instance, a shell variable named `PATH` will overwrite the environment variable `PATH`, whereas `path` is guaranteed not to conflict with names w/ meaning to the OS). Thus, the standard reserves the namespace of names containing at least one lower-case character for application use to avoid conflicts.

Comment: ...BTW, I took the liberty of rewriting the question to provide a MCVE -- a minimal example that showcases the problem, and that anyone can run just by copy-and-pasting (without, for instance, needing to create a bunch of *.txt files first). See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for a description of the guidelines around the practice.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is actually in how you're breaking things down into a one-liner. Your code is equivalent to this:

```
for file in *.dat; do
  printf "$file "
  if grep -q 'hit' "$file"; then
    HITS=$((HITS+1))
    echo "hit"
  else
    MISSES=$((MISSES+1)) echo "miss"
  fi
done
```

See how this has

```
MISSES=$((MISSES+1)) echo "miss"
```

...all on one line? That's your bug. Add a semicolon, or newline:

```
MISSES=$((MISSES+1)); echo "miss"
```

...the former version exports the new value for `MISSES` in the environment for the duration of the `echo` command, but doesn't change it outside that scope; the latter one actually updates it.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. Is using  'let ' a bad practice? Also once I get 2 more rep I will be able to upvote your comment.

Comment: I wouldn't say *bad*, exactly, but it's an *antiquated* practice -- not preferred for new code targeting modern shells.